# Cron settings in parallel plesk

Tags: php, cron, plesk

I try to set a cron job for my site. I am using parallel plesk 11.0.9 .
I am using the below commands

- env php -q /var/www/vhosts/site.ca/httpdocs/crone.php
- /var/www/vhosts/site.ca/httpdocs/crone.php
- /usr/bin/php -q /var/www/vhosts/fpmls.ca/httpdocs/test.php

  etc . But it shows the below errors
- No such file or directory
- env: command not found
- /usr/bin/php: No such file or directory

Comment: Why you used /usr/bin/php, Either use "php" instead or use the correct path of php if you know.

Answer (score 0):

PHP might not be available in the chrooted environment.

This KB article might help: http://kb.sp.parallels.com/en/115842

Comment: Link is broken. This should now be correct: https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/213909545-How-to-add-programs-to-a-chrooted-shell-environment-template-in-Plesk